# The status of my paper is "Ready for Decision (30 days)". Should I write an email and ask?

Tags: publications, peer-review

I submitted my paper in Elsevier, the status of my paper is "Ready for Decision (30 days). Should I write an email and ask why does it takes so long?
Thanks

Comment: Wondering if you ever got a decision on this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 30 days is well past the normal range to make a decision after all reviews have been received.

Comment: Thanks Allure, I just chat with the Elsevier service and they said that they will contact with the Editor and I will receive email from the Editor within 5 working days

Comment: after waiting, now the status is "Ready for Decision (57 days)"